Scroll position when opening the keyboard as in "Telegram"
@Composable
fun ChatScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    // ...
) {
    // ...

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp),
            state = scrollState,
        ) {
            // ...
        }

        MessageInput(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp).imePadding(),
            // ...
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
    }
}

When I use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and imePadding() with MessageInput, when you open the keyboard, messages that were visible before are hidden.

I tried using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and removed  imePadding() from MessageInput. Now the keyboard doesn't close the last visible message, but the list of messages goes off-screen and I can't scroll to the first message.

I would like that when the keyboard is opened, the last message is displayed on the screen, and the scroll position remains unchanged. As it was when using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". At the same time, so that the content does not go beyond the screen and all previous messages are visible.
Everything works as it should when using
LazyColumn(
    // ...
    reverseLayout = true
)

But of course, all messages are displayed in reverse order, and new ones are added to the top of the list...
